# Where to load the data to fill a viewmodel with more than one poco class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have to show an object (a POCO class) in a form.

In my controller, i get the objects data from the objects repository.

But in the form, i have to show some extra data about the object as well, like the country name and not the countryid, the number of persons assigned (to fetch from a 1:N relation), the history of edits (to fetch from yet another table) and the bit 'CanBeCancelled'.

**The question is: where should i put this logic?**

I came up with these alternatives:

- The repository itself: create an extra function which returns this
  exact viewmodel
- a conversionservice, which converts the class to the
  viewmodel (it knows where to get the data)
- the controller: it knows
  what data to show in the view(model), so it should get all the data
  from the different repositories

What is a good way to place this logic (with 'this logic' i mean the logic to know that the number of persons is fetched in repository A, the history is fetched by repository B and the countryname is fetched by the CountryRepository and the boolean 'CanBeCancelled' is fetched by the StateEngine service) ?

Comment: These kind of questions arise because i learned OO a long time ago (from Delphi devs) who used to, like OO was presented that days, put everything about an object in that object. So the PErson class had all logic about the person, all properties, all methods, all behaviour, even the knowledge to save itself to the database. Lots of patterns i read today still assume this is the way to go. But in the other books i read nowadays, we have to seperate concerns, so everything is in a separate object, so i have to create POCO, repositories and services for the behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no other constraints, I would follow simple rule stated by [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - each layer should do its own job and presume that other layers do their job properly. In this case repositories return the business object, services process the business object and the controller only knows how to display the object properly. In details:

1. Number of persons, history and country name are already in the storage, and should come from there. So repository should return a complete object - as long as the operations are about the same entity.
2. When several entities are involved in the process, service is responsible for calling corresponding repositories and constructing an object.
3. Things that are figured out according to the business rules are the job for service object as well.
4. Controller receives complete object by calling single method of a service and displays it

Benefits of this approach will be evident once you decide to *change* something, say business rule about how the object is allowed to be cancelled. This has nothing to do with access to the database, and does not involve application UI, so the only place you want to change in this case is service implementation. This approach allows you to do just that, without need to alter code of repositories and controllers.

Comment: Ok, about item 1: was not sure about the repository calling other repositories vs a service calling the other repositories. Should this repos have any knowledge about getting data for a specific viewmodel or not.

Comment: About item 3: thats my general way of doing also, make a service class responsible for the end result. Is this kind of class called a `facade`?

Comment: @Michel, item 1 - actually it all depends on the situation. According to the repository pattern, one repository should completely take care about one entity. As soon as there are several entities involved in the process - service becomes responsible for the job. I might be slightly mistaken here and will update the answer shortly. As to facade - it is a slightly different concept. Facade is about simplifying interface of some complicated system.